# create a vector (multiple columns in one new column) pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vector

Please, i have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {
    "a": [420, 380, 390],
    "b": [50, 40, 45],
    "c": [30, 22, 11],
    "d": [323, 2, 33]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
a   b   c    d
0  420  50  30  323
1  380  40  22    2
2  390  45  11   33
```

and i want to get this result:

```
    a   d
        b   c    d
0  420  50  30  323
1  380  40  22    2
2  390  45  11   33
```

do you have any suggestions ?

i tried merge and concatenate but not working for me

Comment: Use this: `df.columns = [list("addd"), list("abcd")]`, which sets the columns as a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)

Comment: Do you have any sort of methodology on why you are transforming this dataset, or do you just want to set the column headers?

Comment: i want to create file with vector "d" that grouping list of columns, to use it in my workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using pd.MultiIndex:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[*'addd'],[*' bcd']])
```

Output:

```
     a   d         
         b   c    d
0  420  50  30  323
1  380  40  22    2
2  390  45  11   33
```